# VSCode resolve variable cannot be resolved error in editor for *.xsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, xslt, reference, deltaxml

I am using VSCode application to develop *.xsl files.

I am using an *.xsl file holding global variables which I use accross the project and include it in other files. However these parameters/variables are highlighted by VSCode as missing reference when imported indirectly only at runtime.

Can this be resolved in VSCode editor to include other files in a project setup when looking for references?

---

Example:

**fileA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
<xsl:include href="./fileB.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="./fileC.xsl"/>

<xsl:variable name="varA">Variable directly defined in file A</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$varA"/> <!-- directly available -->
<xsl:value-of select="$varB"/> <!-- include works at runtime at in UI -->
<xsl:value-of select="$varC"/> <!-- include works at runtime at in UI -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**fileB**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="varB">Variable defined in other file B</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$varB"/> <!-- directly available -->
<xsl:value-of select="$varC"/>  <!-- include works at runtime, but error in UI -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**fileC**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="varC">Variable defined in other file C</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$varC"/> <!-- directly available -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**sub/fileD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">

<xsl:variable name="varD">Variable defined in other file D in sub dir</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$varD"/> <!-- directly available -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

fileA

- defines `varA`
- includes files B and C
- does not include file D
- can resolve own variable `varA` and the ones from included files `varB` and `varC` at runtime and in UI

fileB

- defines `varB`
- can resolve own variable `varB`
- does not include file C (explicitly)
- can resolve `varC` at runtime since included by fileA, but not in UI (warning)

fileC

- defines `varC`
- can resolve own variable `varC`

sub/fileC

- defines `varD`
- can resolve own variable `varD`

So fileA includes files B+C and can resolve all variables at runtime and without warning in UI. The sub/fileD is not included directly, but can be found in sub-directory, hence UI warns about "*XPath: The variable/parameter ... cannot be resolved here, but it may be defined in an external module*"

FileB tries to resolve `varC`, but does no include fileC. At runtime it is resolved by fileA including fileB and fileC, so no error at runtime. UI however cannot find `varC` and flags it as "*XPath: The variable/parameter $varA cannot be resolved*"

You might be asking why not simply include fileC in fileB to resolve it!? Reason is, that I am supporting different languages. Hence the root *.xsl file imports different files, depending on the langugage settings. Each langugage *.xsl defines the same variables in the given langugage. The templates use the common variables to display texts in the given language. Hence I rely on the root import at runtime.

Can I tell the UI somehow, that these variables exist, even though the file is no included? Like adding it to a project setup or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm assuming you're using [DeltaXML's XSLT/XPath extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xslt-xpath) for VSCode (which I maintain):

In your examples, `fileA.xsl` and `fileB.xsl` and `fileC.xsl` are the only files (XSLT modules) that reference externally defined variables. So we can safely ignore `sub/fileD.xsl`.

**The current behaviour:**

- If you open `fileB.xsl` first:

  - the references to `$varB` and `$varC` **are not** resolved because it's defined in `fileA.xsl`
- If you open `fileA.xsl` first:

  - the external references to `$varB` and `$varC` are resolved because the `xsl:include` instructions cause VSCode to load all symbols defined in `fileB.xsl` and `fileC.xsl`
- If you open `fileB.xsl` **after** opening `fileA.xsl`:

  - the external references to `$varB` and `$varC` **are** resolved - the information that `fileB.xsl` and `fileC.xsl` are included by `fileA.xsl` was stored when you opened `fileA.xsl`

**The Answer:**

To get the behaviour you need (resolve `$varC` from `fileB.xsl`), you just need to go back and open `fileA.xsl` if you've opened `fileB.xsl` first.

**Note:** *you may need to 'refresh' `fileB.xsl` in VSCode after this by closing/reopening it.*

*VSCode with **Peek References** invoked from the `$varC` reference in `fileB.xsl`*:

[image]

---

**A final point:**

This behaviour is admittedly not seamless, but it does mean there is no need to have a proprietary project setup that would need to be maintained and shared with others. It may be of interest that there is a ['main-module' proposal](https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/87) for XSLT 4.0 that seeks to address this issue.